# Creating a multidimensional (4d) array in Java with unique objects in each element

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2d array of objects within another 2d array in Java. The array is 8 by 8, so 64 objects need to be initialized into the array. As tedious as this already sounds, I then have to do this 64 times... And, to make it even more difficult, the location of specific objects in each 2d array is different so I can't just use a simple for loop.

So my main question is, is there any way that anyone can think of that would allow me to speed up the process of initializing each slot in the 2d array? Methods? Loops? Anything?

There's about 10 unique objects that will be placed in specified slots in the 2d array, one of which is a specific object that will be the most common throughout the arrays.

The way I'm currently intending to do it is to have a class with a 2d array that is 8 by 8, and use the constructor to load in the objects, and place them into the array. I would then do this 64 times, creating a unique 2d array of objects for each element in my larger 2d array of 2d arrays (I guess that makes it a 4d array?)
This is the general idea of code I'm planning to follow:

```
public class Books{ 
private items[][] layout = new items[8][8];
public Books(items a1, items a2, items a3, items a4, items a5, items a6, items a7, items a8, items a9, items a10 etc. etc.){ 
layout[0][0] = a1; layout[0][1] = a2; layout[0][2] = a3; layout[0][4] = a4; layout[0][5] = a5; etc. etc. }
```

As you can see this is already incredibly tedious, plus, I then have to initialize each Book in my main class:

```
Books[][] bks = new books[8][8];
bks[0][0] = Books(i1, i2, i1, i4, i1, i1, i1, i8, i9, etc. etc.);
bks[0][1] = Books(i7, i1, i8, i1, i4, i2, i7, i1, i1, etc. etc.);
```

Is there any way to make my life easier? Or am I destined to manually input 4096 (64*64) objects into my program?

Comment: The typical approach is to put the data you are initializing the data structure from into a file or files, and read it / them on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object 2D array, and fill it with 2D arrays. When performing functions on the inside 2D array, be sure to cast it. to a 2D array. For instance, I could have a gameButtons 2D array of objects, with a 2D array of JButtons inside. I would do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < gameButtons[i].length; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < ((JButton[][]) gameButtons[i][j]).length; k++)
            for (int l = 0; l < ((JButton[][]) gameButtons[i][j])[k].length; l++)
                ((JButton[][]) gameButtons[i][j])[k][l] = new JButton();
```